# Trouble Importing fs Module in JavaScript File to Read txt File. The js file is linked to HTML File

Tags: javascript, html, webdev.webserver

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to import the fs module in my JavaScript file to read a txt file, which I've linked to my HTML file. Despite my efforts, the JavaScript file fails to establish a link with the HTML file, preventing the successful execution of my file reading operations.

I have saved my javascript file as '.mjs' because it doesn't work at all with the normal '.js' extention

```
import fs from 'fs'
```

this is how i have imported the file

this is how I've linked it to my html file

```
    <script type="module"src="fileReadTest.mjs"></script>
```

and this is the error im getting on my dev console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2F6K.png)

Comment: there's no 'fs' module in a browser

Comment: does it still now work even if you export the result from using the fs module to another script and then link the new script to the html file @AlexanderNenashev